# why GTX630 is faster for me than GTX650Ti for opencl?

Tags: opencl

I am using two graphics card for opencl code

using profiling, my GTX 630 kepler is running faster than GTX650 Ti for each method request.

[image]

after profiling i found out some differences for both graphics card. But i am not able to understand what **occupancy, l1_global_load_hit, l1_global_load_miss, active_warps and active_cycles** are less for GTX650 Ti. Can any one please help me understand these terms in a more better way.

Comment: As manual says: Occupancy : Occupancy is the ratio of the number of active warps per multiprocessor to the maximum number of active warps. l1 global load hit: Number of global load hits in L1 cache. l1 global load miss: Number of global load misses in L1 cache. active warps: Accumulated number of active warps per cycle. For every cycle it increments by the number of active warps in the cycle which can be in the range 0 to 48. active cycles: Number of cycles a multiprocessor has at least one active warp.

Comment: There are two different types of GT630. It could be that yours is a Fermi meaning that the architecture of the two GPUs is different and your code runs better in one then the other.

Comment: i am using http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-630/specifications GT630 kepler with 384 cuda cores.. And other one GT650Ti http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-650ti/specifications

Comment: @talonmies thanks for your reply.. can you please help me out for the reason why this runs faster in 630? i also profiled the code.. can see lower values too.. but couldn;t understand real why?

Comment: If the occupancy of the 650 would be full, then it would be faster. So, the question here is: "Why 100% usage is not reached on the 650?"

Comment: What are NDRange & Localgroup sizes?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan NDRange is 1024

Comment: @DarkZeros i was also thinking the same... but i dont why occupancy is not full?? is it something wrong from the code?? Do i need to post the code?? Or something related to machine configuration?

Comment: Can you increase NDRange size, say, to 16384 and see what will change?

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan  i can change it, but why 16384 only?? And my calculations are dependent of get_global_id(0) hence it might give me wrong results. but i can run empty rest.. but can you give me some reason..

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan my occupancy had become 1. but rest effect is same... please help me out what occupancy is? and why you made it 16*1024?? how come you figure out the difference?? and what about rest terms?? i am trying it to read it online but couldn't find much..

Comment: 16384 was just a guess. Idea is that 630 has less power under the hood, so that relatively small NDRange can be handled more efficiently, than in case of 650 (I don't know Nvidia GPUs well). Usually, the more threads you spawn, the better GPU feels.

Comment: so what does actually occupancy means @RomanArzumanyan ??? and what is active warps and active cycles? how come occupancy became 1 after increasing WG??

Comment: As you said in first comment, occupancy is ratio of running threads number to available threads number. E. g. your stream processing unit has 64 ALUs. If you make local group of size 48, then occupancy will be 48/64 = 0.75. I don't know exact reason, why occupancy on your 650Ti was 50%, but my guess was that bigger NDSize gives smaller modulo.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease local work group size from 1024 down to 512 or 256 maybe even 64, then try again. This will leave more local memory per wave of threads. So more will execute simultaneously henceforth occupying more ALUs.

Don't forget to make the total number of threads a multiple of 768(number of cores of your faster card) to actually fill it evenly through all cores.(not just multiple of 384 like 1k-is which is not good for your faster card)